# Integral $\int_0^a \ln \left( \frac{b-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{b+\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} \right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Hi I am trying to calculate,

$$
\int_0^a \ln \left( \frac{b-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{b+\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}    \right)dx
$$
where $a,b$ are positive real constants.  I Know $\ln(xy)=\ln x +\ln y$, but I do not know how to evaluate this integral then.
I need to find a closed form for the indefinite integral 
$$
\int \ln \big(b\pm \sqrt{a^2-x^2}\big) dx
$$
so this is really the problem I am facing.  The closed form exists and is in terms of elementary functions.  Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Note that $\large \ln(\frac{x}{y})=\ln(x)-\ln(y)$

Comment: @AlijahAhmed I know that. however I need to prove the closed form result

Comment: @Jeff, to clarify. Is it correct that you do not know how to compute $\int \ln (b \pm \sqrt{a^2-x^2}) dx$?

Comment: @nayrb Yes exactly

Comment: Okay - thanks for clarifying the question.

Comment: It is enough to compute $\int \ln(a+\sqrt{1-x^2})dx$ (after change of variables and algebra).

Comment: @nayrb I am aware of this algebra too.  I need to calculate that integral though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a possible way (I assume $a\geq 0$, $b\geq 0$):

1) substitute $x= a \sin t $.

2) integrate the resulting integral by parts to get rid of $\ln$

3) you should end up with $$-\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{2 a^2 b \sin^2 t\,dt }{b^2 -a^2 \cos^2 t} .$$

4) it is possible to integrate the last integral  by elementary means or using the residue theorem. You should obtain $$\pi \left(\sqrt{b^2 -a^2}  -b\right).$$

**Edit:**

Here are the steps in a bit more detail ($0\leq a \leq b$):

1) after subsitution $x= a \sin t$ with $dx = a \cos t\, dt$ we obtain
$$ a \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \!dt\,\cos t\, \ln \left( \frac{b -a \cos t}{b+a \cos t} \right). $$

2) Integration by parts (where $\cos t$ is integrated and the rest differentiated) leads directly to
$$ a \sin t \, \ln \left( \frac{b -a \cos t}{b+a \cos t} \right) \Bigg|_{0}^{\pi/2} - a \int_0^{\pi/2}\!dt\, \sin t \frac{b+ a \cos t}{b -a \cos t} \frac{2 a b}{(b+ a \cos t)^2} \sin t\\
= - 2 a^2 b \int_0^{\pi/2}\!dt\, \frac{\sin^2 t}{b^2 -a ^2 \cos^2 t}.$$

3) Now use the substitution $s= \tan t$ with $ds = (1+s^2) dt =\cos^{-2} t\, dt$ as proposed by sos440. This leads to
$$ -2 a^2 b \int_0^{\infty}\!\frac{ds}{1+s^2}\, \frac{\sin^2 t}{b^2 -a^2\cos^2 t}
= -2 a^2 b \int_0^{\infty}\!ds\, \frac{s^2}{(1+s^2)[b^2 (1+s^2)-a^2]}.$$

4) Employing the partial fraction expansion on the last integrand, you obtain
$$ -2 b \int_0^\infty\frac{ds}{1+s^2} +  \frac{2(b^2-a^2)}{b} \int_0^\infty \frac{ds}{s^2 +1 - (a/b)^2}   .$$
Thus, we need to evaluate the integral
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{ds}{s^2+\alpha^2} 
= \alpha^{-1} \arctan(s/\alpha) \big|_{0}^{\infty} = \frac{\pi}{2\alpha},$$
and we obtain the final result (with $\alpha=1$ and $\alpha= \sqrt{1-(a/b)^2}$)
$$ -\pi b + \frac{(b^2-a^2)\pi}{b \sqrt{1-(a/b)^2}} .$$

Comment: +1 for the residue theorem and for not ignoring the upper bound.

Comment: +1 for the elementary mean. We can use the substitution $s = \tan t$ to the integral in the 3rd step.

Comment: @sos440: thanks  for making this point more explicit. I had indeed the substitution $s=\tan t$ in mind... ($\tan t/2$ is an overkill in this case)

Comment: @Fabian the integral in the 3rd step, should it be $\cos^2 t$ or $\cos t$?

Comment: @Jeff: if I did not do a mistake, It should be $\cos^2 t$.

Comment: @sos440 why does the substitution $s=\tan t$ work here?  Even though we usually the half angle tan substitution.  Is this is a special case where they both work?

Comment: @Jeff, There is two ways of understanding this substiution. (1) Using the double-angle formula for $\cos 2t$, we can modify the integrand to an expression only involving $\cos 2t$. Then $x = \tan t$ is now a usual Weierstarss substitution. (2) We can use the formula $\sec^{2}t = 1 + \tan^{2} t$ to modify the integrand to a form $R(\tan t) \sec^{2} t$ for some rational function $R(x)$.

Comment: @Fabian I have been trying since yesterday to get it into that closed final form you have.  I will gladly show you all my steps if you want.  But how did you get it in that closed form in step 4)?  I even checked the integral numerically and it cannot get it into that simple form.  Although I know it is correct.  Thanks...

Comment: @sos440 After your idea of changing variables and simplifications, I obtained
$$
-4a^2b\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)(b^2-2a^2+b^2x^2)} dx.
$$
This integral is straightforward except I cannot produce the closed form result posted with it.  Thanks

Comment: @Jeff: the your result is not completely correct. I have expanded my answer. Please feel free to ask if you still cannot reproduce it...

Comment: @Fabian I will go through this later, and get back to you if i have questions.  although it seems very clear, thanks...

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to compute $\int \ln(a+\sqrt{1-x^2}) dx$.

Do a change of variables $x=\sin t$ and integrate by parts:
$$\int \ln (a+\cos t) \cos t \, dt = \ln(a+\cos t) \sin t + \int \frac{\sin^2 t}{a+\cos t} \, dt$$

Use the substitution $u = \tan t/2$ so that $\sin t = 2u/(1+u^2)$, $\cos t = (1-u^2)/(1+u^2)$ and $dt = 2/(1+u^2) du$. This is known as the Weierstrass substitution. This gives for the integral on the RHS

$$\int \frac{4u^2}{(1+u^2)^2} \frac{1}{a+(1-u^2)/(1+u^2)} \frac{2}{1+u^2}du$$
or
$$\int \frac{4u^2}{(1+u^2)^2} \frac{1}{(a-1)u^2+(a+1)} \frac{2}{1+u^2}du.$$

Now we have a giant partial fractions problem. So it's doable, but a pain. I've sort of lost interest going further, but it explains the complexity of the solution you get with wolfram alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+log%28b+%2B+sqrt%28a%5E2-x%5E2%29%29+dx

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks a lot Nayrb

Comment: You're welcome!